# How to save captcha image in Gecko web browser c#

Tags: c#, captcha, gecko

I'm trying to create a bot for a browser game using C# and I have to use the Gecko web browser.

The game login page has captcha and if I open the image link, the captcha will be change. So I need to save the captcha image on disk and use it in a picture box, but i don't know how.

The captcha image is **without** any **name** or **id** tag and **the source** is: `code.php?938080`.

I found [*Catching captcha image*](http://koolprogrammer.blogspot.fr/2009/05/catching-captcha-image-part-1-c.html), but I don't know how to convert it for my case and Gecko.

```
foreach (HtmlElement img in wb.Document.Images)
{

    isitcaptcha = img.OuterHtml.IndexOf("Captcha", 0);
    if (isitcaptcha > 0)
    {
        captchaimg = img.OuterHtml.ToString();
```

**it says:**

```
Cannot convert type 'Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement'

The name 'isitcaptcha' does not exist in the current context    

The name 'captchaimg' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: why is **php** tagged?

Comment: suggested tags! idk maybe helped

Comment: Suggested tags are automatic and you can add/remove as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you should be using GeckoHtmlElement object of Gecko.DOM namespace.
And declare your variables...

```
foreach (GeckoHtmlElement img in wb.Document.Images)
{

var isitcaptcha = img.OuterHtml.IndexOf("Captcha", 0);
if (isitcaptcha > 0)
{
    var captchaimg = img.OuterHtml.ToString();
```